# Python - non-blocking sockets using selectors

Tags: python, sockets, select

My Problem in short:
I dont know how the selector knows which socket should read or write first.

It is a Server that can handle multi connections and its flow should be:

1. Server creates listening socket
2. Client creates 2 sockets and connects them to the server
3. Client 2 sockets send the messages
4. Server 2 sockets echo those messages, client and server closing
   connection

which is what happens, but if the created server sockets would write first, the connection would be closed immediately or throw an exception(?), since it doesn't even call send and the client socket would recv nothing. So how does the selector know which sockets should be ready to write/read first? Which information do i miss to understand this?

Server:

```
import socket
import selectors
import types

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 63210

def accept_wrapper(sock):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print('accepted connection from', addr)
    conn.setblocking(False)
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(addr=addr, inb=b'', outb=b'')
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)

def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print('closing connection to', data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if data.outb:
            print('echoing', repr(data.outb), 'to', data.addr)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
lsock.bind((host, port))
lsock.listen()
print('listening on', (host, port))
lsock.setblocking(False)
sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)

while True:
    events = sel.select(timeout=None)
    for key, mask in events:
        if key.data is None:
            accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
        else:
            service_connection(key, mask)
```

Client:

```
import socket
import selectors
import types

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 63210
num_conns = 2
messages = [b'Message 1 from client.', b'Message 2 from client.']

def start_connections(host, port, num_conns):
    server_addr = (host, port)
    for i in range(0, num_conns):
        connid = i + 1
        print('starting connection', connid, 'to', server_addr)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setblocking(False)
        sock.connect_ex(server_addr)
        events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
        data = types.SimpleNamespace(connid=connid,
                                     msg_total=sum(len(m) for m in messages),
                                     recv_total=0,
                                     messages=list(messages),
                                     outb=b'')
        sel.register(sock, events, data=data)

def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            print('received', repr(recv_data), 'from connection', data.connid)
            data.recv_total += len(recv_data)
        if not recv_data or data.recv_total == data.msg_total:
            print('closing connection', data.connid)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if not data.outb and data.messages:
            data.outb = data.messages.pop(0)
        if data.outb:
            print('sending', repr(data.outb), 'to connection', data.connid)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
start_connections(host, port, num_conns)

while True:
    events = sel.select(timeout=None)
    for key, mask in events:
        service_connection(key, mask)
```

Comment: I perhaps should notice that i hardly understand how select() exactly works and i do not find the docs description really helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sockets don't actually write directly to the peer and they don't read from the peer. Instead they write into a local socket specific write buffer and read from a socket specific read buffer. The OS kernel cares about the delivery of the data from the socket write buffer to the peer and puts received packets from the peer into the sockets receive buffer.

The status of these in-kernel socket buffers and changes to these buffers can be monitored with functions like `select`, `poll`, `kqueue`. In essence: a socket is considered writable if there is room in the sockets write buffer. A socket is considered readable if there are data in the sockets read buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked at the same code that you have, and have raised a pull request for precisely the concern that you have:
https://github.com/realpython/materials/pull/112

Essentially, the answer is that the sockets and read+write events are cycled by the system in a loop. Eventually every socket becomes available to read and write in this loop and you just have to wait for the turn to occur.