# What are the value states of read/write in selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, client-server, bitwise-operators

In the question [Python - non-blocking sockets using selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045592/python-non-blocking-sockets-using-selectors) the following code is used:

`events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE`

The values of event_read or event_write flags are not mentioned nor explained at https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html. Neither is an explanation give in the `select()` module or given at https://realpython.com/python-sockets/. It would be appreciated to emphasize on this particular part or provide reading material that explains this in much more detail than provided by python docs or the realpython link.

In relation, during service connection this is used: `if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:`

I can imaging that the evaluation can be 1 & 1 or 2 & 2 and in both cases the code within the if-statement is executed. So if the expression evaluates 3 & 1 it would not execute, right?

The code:

```
def service_connection(key, mask):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print('closing connection to', data.addr)
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if data.outb:
            print('echoing', repr(data.outb), 'to', data.addr)
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]
```

Comment: @SteffenUllrich perhaps you can elaborate on the events_read and events_write state? I found your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53045592/python-non-blocking-sockets-using-selectors but not satisfying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the python `selectors.py` file the following variables are created:

1. `EVENT_READ = (1 << 0)`
2. `EVENT_WRITE = (1 << 1)`

If both are printed the following values are given for each state:

```
print(EVENT_READ)  = 1

print(EVENT_WRITE) = 2
```

What happens is the following (a bitwise shift to the left):

`bin(0b1) -> '0b1'  # bitwise operator for EVENT_READ = (1 << 0)`

`bin(0b1) -> '0b10' # bitwise operator for EVENT_WRITE = (1 << 1)`

In the case of `if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:` a "bitwise and" is applied. Each bit of the output is 1 if the corresponding bit of `mask` AND of `selectors.EVENT_READ` is 1, otherwise it's 0.

```
mask = integer # 0, 1, 2, 3 or higher.

if mask & EVENT_READ:
    print ('mask & EVENT_READ')
    
if mask & EVENT_WRITE:
    print ('mask & EVENT_WRITE')
```

1. if mask = 0  | None of the above if-statements is true for below.
2. if mask = 1  | Only the ***event_read*** is true.
3. if mask = 2  | Only the ***event_write*** is true.
4. if mask = 3  | Both if statements are true.

The if-statement validation value output and order for each mask value repeats itself for mask = 5, 6, etc..

Bitwise operators references [1](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) and [2](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/bitwise_left_shift.html).